# Error: The first argument must be a File or Blob object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Hello I am using compressorjs plugin when select images then issue is

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressorjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressorjs#options)

My Code is :-

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          imageData,
          fileEntry => {
            fileEntry.file(file => {
              console.log(file);
              new Compressor(file, {
                quality: 0.6,
                success: result => {
                  console.log(result, result.size);
                },
                error: err => {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              });
            });
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
```

[image: Getting issue when select images]

Comment: a cordova File instance is not the same as `window.File`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @endless has said you can't use a cdvfile path because it's a custom filepath handler, however you can change a cdvfile path to a native path

It's under the heading `Converting cdvfile:// to native path` on the documentation https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    resolveLocalFileSystemURL('cdvfile://localhost/temporary/path/to/file.mp4', 
        function(entry) {
            var nativePath = entry.toURL();
            console.log('Native URI: ' + nativePath);
        }
    );

}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

A cordova File instance is not the same as [window.File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) cordova creates a file like object but it ain't the same as `something instanceOf File` cuz compressorjs probably only has knowledge of File and Blob, not cordova files.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

> This plugin defines global cordova.file object.
>
> Although in the global scope, it is not available until after the deviceready event.

I don't know much about cordova or compressorjs, but it sounds to me that you can load compressorjs after the `deviceready` event